# Unable to handle confrimation box with selenium RC

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

i am trying to press the ok button from a confirmation box like this (i added Thread.spleep so i checked the button is pressed and the confirmation box is shown)

```
selenium.chooseOkOnNextConfirmation(); 
selenium.click("xpath=//a[contains(@href,'123')]");
assertTrue(selenium.getConfirmation().equalsIgnoreCase("123"));
```

but i get this

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: There were no confirmations
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:97)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:91)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:262)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.getConfirmation(DefaultSelenium.java:429)
```

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with the code

```
selenium.chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation();//点击cancel按钮
selenium.click("link=Delete");
selenium.getConfirmation();
```

Finally I find the reason is that the developer used the `jconfirm` function of jquery instead of `window.confirm`, and the `jconfirm` function is override with div.

Finally I used `assertTrue(selenium.isElementPresent("id=popup_container"))`.

Answer (score 0):

from this information it is hard to say exactly. but i will give you some info which will help you

java script generates 3 types of pop-up windows

1) Alerts
2)Confirmations
3)Prompts

your case, i guess

1) may be the statement selenium.click() you used, is not triggering the confirmation box

OR

2) if it is triggering, then it may not be the Confirmation box.it could be any one of the other 2 boxes

so, you must make sure manually what type of pop-up window it is and call the statements accordingly.

ex : Confirmation window  : conatins OK and Cancel buttons
Alert window : contains only OK button
Prompt window : contains Textbox and OK and Cancel buttons

so check and use that commands respectively

if it is not the above case please the HTML code also